# How to vertically center text with an image in the same row of a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I want to create a table with multiple rows of the following form: a cell that contains text and then multiple cells that contain images. The text should be vertically centered and the contents of every column should also be centered horizontally. I am aware of the `m{}` column type but somehow this seems to fail if an image is contained in the row and determines the row height. Any ideas?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{m{3cm}c}
(a) & \includegraphics{some_picture.pdf}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit. Also, it isn't really a custom here to sign with a "thanks". Finally a suggestion: Maybe change your username to something more telling than "user5506"?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The baseline of an image is at the bottom. You could use `\raisebox` to shift it up. Use half of `\height`, which stands for the height of the box to be raised.

```
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics{some_picture}}
```

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}} & text & text\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

yields:

[image]

Answer (score 57):

The new [`graphbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphbox) package introduces a new (vertical) `align` key which can be used in `\includegraphics` options. Using it there's no need for `\raisebox`, `\parbox` or taking care of distinguishing between `c` or `m` columns in tabulars.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphbox} %loads graphicx package
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
text & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & text\\
text & \includegraphics[align=c,scale=0.25]{example-image} & text\\
text & \includegraphics[align=t,scale=0.25]{example-image} & text\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As `egreg` reminded me, [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package provides a similar funcionality. Loading it with `export` option, a new key `valign={t|m|b|T|M|B}` can be used as `\includegraphics` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
text & \includegraphics[valign=m,scale=0.25]{example-image} & text \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The same functionality (with the key `valign`) is available with `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for reminding me about `adjustbox`.

Comment: And thank you for advertising a new package!

Comment: `adjustbox` vetical-aligns  more accurately than `graphbox`. Try the code of this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564995/2288 with `graphbox` and notice the difference.

Answer (score 7):

use the m column type for the image, eg:

```
\begin{tabular}{c m{4cm}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer of Stefan Kottwitz I wrote this little snippet to make it a little easier to implement:

```
\newcommand{\tabfigure}[2]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
```

To be used as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\newcommand{\tabfigure}[2]{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    a bit of text &    \tabfigure{width=0.20\textwidth}{example-image}
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: wanted to write is as comment because it's basically the same answer, but I don't have enough rep yet...

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray): use `stretch=0` and set head alignment (`h`) for images.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  stretch = 0,
  colspec = {Q[h,l]ll},
  hlines,
}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & Alpha & Sigma \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for:

- Wrapped text in text cells
- Manual linebreaks within text cells
- Images and text both vertically centered

Uses **makecell** and **tabularx**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm} c}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image.png} & 
        \makecell[X]{
            Here is \newline
            some manually broken text \newline
            And here is some text that has been automatically wrapped by the use of X in the makecell argument
        }
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image: Image of working example]

**Explanation:**

`\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{3cm} X}`

The tabularx `m` argument creates a column of the paragraph (text-wrap) type with the specified width, with the contents vertically aligned in the middle. This solves the vertical centering problem for the image.

The `X` argument to tabularx and makecell makes the cell or column stretch to fill any remaining space.

`\makecell[X]`

Makecell creates a cell that we can manipulate as a whole, which makes alignment easier.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for text that has manual line breaks and also wraps over lines, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A variant of @Herbert's answer that gives vertically *and* horizontally centered column alignment is the following. (This is my preferred method when not using `\includegraphics`.)

```
\begin{tabular}{
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.4\linewidth} % col width
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.4\linewidth} % col width
}
% an image, tikz picture, etc.
&
% another image, tikz picture, etc.
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the image in the \parbox environment also seems to work.

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
xxx & yyy\parbox{0.6\textwidth}{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{example_image}} \\
\end{tabular}
```

This will vertically center both xxx and yyy with the image.

Comment: HI and welcome. Please, develop your answer by giving an example of use or an MWE. [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: It would be preferable to give fully compilable code starting with `documentclass{}` and ending with `end{document}` so that everyone can easily test your solution.