# Text in table with images is not aligned on top

Tags: tables, beamer, vertical-alignment

I have table with text in the first column and image in second. I want both columns to be top aligned. I use following code:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}l}
Internal state after adding 2 elements & \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{pics/queue_after_add.png} \\
Internal state non-concurrent execution & \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{pics/queue_sequential.png} \\
Internal state concurrent execution & \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{pics/queue_concurrent.png}\\
\end{tabular}
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

I also tried to insert \vspace{0pt} as some thread suggests, but result was the same.

Comment: have you tried adding `\vfill` underneath the text? I seem to recall that that has worked for me before.

Comment: `\vspace{0pt}` would work if the graphics were in a column of type `p{..}`. In l-columns you will have to move the graphics below the baseline with `\raisebox{-\height}{....}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It helped! Thank you! I just thought that I don't need p for image, since it doesn't need wrapping.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you make that an answer here?

Comment: Other two solutions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199644/1952

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\vspace{0pt}` would work if the graphics were in a column of type `p{..}`. In `l`-columns you will have to move the graphics below the baseline with `\raisebox{-\height}{....}`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the package 'array'. And then use m instead of the p boxes you have in argument of tabular environment.

```
\usepackage{array}        
\begin{tabular}{m{3cm}m{5cm}}
    Internal state after adding 2 elements & \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{pics/queue_after_add.png} \\
    Internal state non-concurrent execution & \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{pics/queue_sequential.png} \\
    Internal state concurrent execution & \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{pics/queue_concurrent.png}\\
    \end{tabular}
```

Now I have no idea how this works. I found this solution online, after a painful 4 hours of trying to fix a similar issue. And no forum seems to explain why tabular environment by itself cannot fix this. So counter-intuitive!