# Vertical alignment (top, center, bottom) of figure and two texts in tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Based on [Tabular alignment of text and figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116153/tabular-alignment-of-text-and-figure), my question is how can I get `t`, `c`, `b` alignment of all 3 elements that make part of tabular. The `t` and `c` works fine, but not the `b`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcommand*{\mtab}[2][]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}} #2 \end{tabular}}
\newcommand*{\pbox}[2][c]{\mtab[#1]{\begin{varwidth}[#1]{\linewidth}#2\end{varwidth}}}

\newcommand*{\Logo}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.15\textwidth}<{\hfill}>{\centering}p{0.5\textwidth}>{\hfill}p{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
\pbox[b]{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox\relax}{\Logo}} & \pbox[b]{aaa\\ bbb\\ ccc\\ ddd} & \pbox[b]{eee\\ fff\\ hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh hhh}
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\raisebox` changes the depth of your box and (Apparently) confuses the pbox alignment.  Try it with just `\pbox[b]{\Logo}`.

Comment: The problem with this is that the `top` alignment will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got so many nested boxes; it's very hard to tell what purpose you're expecting them all to serve.  I'm also not sure why you need a tabular environment for any of this.  Perhaps, if you could make that need a bit more clear, I could give you a better answer.

Also, it seems that you are under the impression that the alignment commands of the boxes and tabular environments are relative to each other.  They're not.  The alignment commands are relative to the baseline that each box *sits* on.  In the MWE I'm posting, I construct a red line to show where the baseline is and how everything else is being aligned with respect to it.

Here's an example which hugely cuts down on the number of boxes.  I then illustrate different ways of aligning the various elements:  either through the alignment argument to `tabular` or through using `\raisebox` and its ability to access the dimensions of the box its working on.

```
\documentclass{article}
%..%
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}
%..%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%..%
\newcommand{\showbaseline}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red!60}\hspace*{-1cm}\rule[-0.1pt]{\dimexpr\linewidth+2cm}{0.1pt}}}
\begin{document}


There are way too many boxes:

\noindent
\showbaseline%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
    \raisebox{-0.5\height}%
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{\fill}%
\raisebox{0pt}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \hspace*{\fill}
        \fbox{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}} 
                aqaa\\ bbb\\ cycc\\ dydd
        \end{tabular}}
        \hspace*{\fill}
    \end{minipage}}%
\hspace*{\fill}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth}
        \hspace*{\fill}
        \fbox{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}  
            fff\\ hhh
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{minipage}%


\vspace{\fill}

%-@-(1)---------------------------------------------------------------------
Similar, but with far fewer boxes:  I say \emph{similar} because I'm using
\verb-\hspace*{\stretch{...}}- to achieve part of the effect of your box widths.

\noindent
\showbaseline%
    \raisebox{-0.5\height}%
    {\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{example-image}}
\hspace*{\stretch{1}}%
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}} 
            aqaa\\ bbb\\ cycc\\ dydd
    \end{tabular}}
\hspace*{\stretch{2.45}}%
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}  
        fff\\ hhh
    \end{tabular}}


\vspace{\fill}

%-@-(2)---------------------------------------------------------------------
A different alignment.

\noindent
\showbaseline%
    \raisebox{-\height}%
    {\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{example-image}}
\hspace*{\stretch{1}}%
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} 
            aqaa\\ bbb\\ cycc\\ dydd
    \end{tabular}}
\hspace*{\stretch{2.45}}%
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}  
        fff\\ hhh
    \end{tabular}}


\vspace{\fill}

%-@-(3)---------------------------------------------------------------------
Another alignment:  notice the added \verb-\raisebox- to get the first
\verb-tabular- to completely sit on the baseline and the last
\verb-tabular- environment below the baseline.  This is because
\verb-\raisebox-  has access to the dimensions of the boxes it's working on.

\noindent
\showbaseline%
    % not raising the graphics%\raisebox{-\height}%
    {\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{example-image}}
\hspace*{\stretch{1}}%
    \raisebox{\depth}{%
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} 
            aqaa\\ bbb\\ cycc\\ dydd
    \end{tabular}}}
\hspace*{\stretch{2.45}}%
    \raisebox{-\height}{%
    \fbox{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}  
        fff\\ hhh
    \end{tabular}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Certainly, by nesting boxes, you can achieve various effects *in terms of alignment.*  But, you can also make things unexpectedly more complicated because you're essentially creating multiple baselines:  the *main* baseline of your text and the baselines within each box you're working with.  This can work against you.  And, I believe this is what's leading to your frustration.

Comment: I used the tabular because it seemed to me the easier way to get text and figures aligned and structured. I want this to build a top heading for an university exam: with logo and additional information. You solution seems promising, and it will for sure be used as future reference. I need to look at it carefully. It would be great if you could define somehow a command that depending on the input would use one of the options.