# Align text at the bottom of the table cell

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, tabularx

I need to create table of content in a table format with text wrapping in the subject titles. The page number is currently at the top of each cell. In the rows where the title is wrapped, I need the page number aligned at the bottom. This is my code:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l X l }

  Figure & & Page \\

  1.1.1  &  test text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  \dotfill &  10 \\
  1.1.2 & line \dotfill & 12 \\

\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It helps those trying to help you if you post a complete Minimum Working Example (MWE), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116225/vertical-alignment-top-center-bottom-of-figure-and-two-texts-in-tabular

Comment: You need to know how high the X column entry is, which you could do with a \parbox the same width, but you don't know what the width is/will be with tabularx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the solution you are looking for, although it is a bit clumsy. You have to include `array` package to get option `b{}` for table alignement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{b{0.1\linewidth}b{0.8\linewidth}p{0.1\linewidth}}

  Figure & & Page \\

  1.1.1 & test text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  \dotfill & 10 \\
  1.1.2 & line \dotfill & 12 \\
  1.1.3  &  a lot of text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  \dotfill &  15 \\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The thing you have to do is compile the code above, and look for the lines, where the middle column is on multiple lines:

[image: First compilation]

Then insert `\newline` after the Figure number, so it will move up a line. So in this case the table will look like:

```
\begin{tabular}{b{0.1\linewidth}b{0.8\linewidth}p{0.1\linewidth}}

  Figure & & Page \\

  1.1.1\newline & test text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  \dotfill & 10 \\
  1.1.2 & line \dotfill & 12 \\
  1.1.3\newline\newline  &  a lot of text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  \dotfill &  15 \\

\end{tabular}
```

And the final result:

[image: Final]

Comment: You probably have a table that is larger than `\linewidth` due to `\tabcolsep`s between columns.

Comment: @Werner yes, I usually forget that :D Set the middle column to `0.65\textwidth` and it should be fine.

Comment: ...or `\dimexpr.8\linewidth-6\tabcolsep` and precede the `tabular` with `\noindent`.

Comment: @Werner Fantastic! I always did it manually and now I don't have to. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> [image: table with page numbers]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand\DotsPage [1]{\dotfill\rlap{\kern2\tabcolsep #1}&}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l X l }

  Figure & & Page \\

  1.1.1  &  test text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text
  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text\DotsPage{10}\\
  1.1.2 & line test text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text
  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text\DotsPage {12}\\
  1.1.3 & line for comparison\dotfill & 13 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Such things are almost always better set as a list than as a table, here just using `enumerate` but you may want a custom list format (`enumitem` package might help)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\def\Dotfill{{\def\hfill{\hskip4em plus 1fill}\dotfill}}



\begin{enumerate}

  \item[1.1.1] test text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  \Dotfill  10 
  \item[1.1.2] line \Dotfill  12 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```