# Different vertical alignment of text in 4-column table (tabularx)

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx, cell

I'm newbie in TeX, so I've decided to ask for some help.

I'm working on technical documentation for my job and I need to create a 4-column table, where text in first two columns top-aligned and centered horizontally, last two aligned with last string of second column. But I can't achieve this.

I've tried this: [Align text at the bottom of the table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203428/align-text-at-the-bottom-of-the-table-cell)

and this: [Vertical alignment in tabular cells with variable height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113022/vertical-alignment-in-tabular-cells-with-variable-height)

But the closest result which I able to obtain is:

[image]

So, last three columns is OK, first one - not, it should be top-aligned.

I was successful to overcome this by usage of `\multirow` environment, but it's should be implemented individually to rows. If' I'll do this for long tables - it'll make me insane. I want one fixed style in preamble, if it's possible.

Here is my table in main body:

```
    %russian technichal standart documentation class
     \documentclass[russian, 14pt, utf8, columnsxxiv, columnxxxi, columnxxxii, pointsection, hpadding = 10mm]{eskdtext}

     %%%For working of eskdx, also cyrillic
     \usepackage{xecyr}

     %%%set TNR as main font
     \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}

     %%%Additional position options
     \usepackage{float}

     %%%advanced tables
     \usepackage{tabularx}
     \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}      
     \newcolumntype{d}{>{\centering}b{.25\textwidth}}
     \newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering}b{.1\textwidth}}
     \newcolumntype{a}{>{\centering}p{.25\textwidth}}

     %%%redefine command for № -symbol, because eskdx quite old package
     \renewcommand{\No}{\textnumero}

     \begin{document}

     \begin{table}[H]
     \label{appA}
     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{a|d|s|Y}
     \hline 
     Наименование & Основные технические данные & Кол., шт. & Примечание  \\ 
     \hline
     text text text text text text text & text text text text text text text text text text& {1} & text  \\ 
     \end{tabularx} 
     \end{table}

     \end{document}
```

I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: your codes snippets aren't very helpful. please, be so kind and merge and extent them to complete small document, called mwe (minimal working example) beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand your request, the following solves the problem (sorry for poor representation of Russian language by Latin characters):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
      \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
      \newcolumntype{d}{>{\centering}b{.25\textwidth}}
      \newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering}b{.1\textwidth}}
      \newcolumntype{a}{>{\centering}p{.25\textwidth}}
    \newcolumntype{c}{>{\centering}b{.25\textwidth}<{\vfill}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
     \label{appA}
 %    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{a|d|s|Y}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|d|s|Y}
     \hline 
     Naimenovanije& Osnovnyje tehniceskije dannyje & Kol.,   &sht. Primechanije  \\ 
     \hline
     text text text text text text text & text text text text text text text 
     text text text & {1} & text  \\ 
     \hline
     \end{tabularx} 
     \end{table}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I'm need! Many thanks, Przemysław Scherwentke!

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid breaking off the last line of the paragraph "by hand" by just backing up by a line;

```
  %russian technichal standart documentation class
     \documentclass[russian, 14pt, utf8, columnsxxiv, columnxxxi, columnxxxii, pointsection, hpadding = 10mm]{eskdtext}

     %%%For working of eskdx, also cyrillic
     \usepackage{xecyr}

     %%%for fonts
% don't use these     \usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}

%  this is already loaded     \usepackage{fontspec}

    \def\No{???}% undefined command in MWE 

     %%%set TNR as main font
     \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}

     %%%Additional position options
     \usepackage{float}

     %%%advanced tables
     \usepackage{tabularx}
     \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} %%% центрированный тип блока          ячейки для tabularx
     \newcolumntype{d}{>{\centering}p{.25\textwidth}}
     \newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering}p{.1\textwidth}}
     \newcolumntype{a}{>{\centering}p{.25\textwidth}}

     \begin{document}

     \begin{table}[H]
     \label{appA}
     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{a|d|s|Y}
     \hline 
     Наименование & Основные технические данные & Кол., шт. & Примечание  \\ 
     \hline
     text text text text text text text & text text text text text text text text text text&&\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
     && {1} & text  \\ 
     \end{tabularx} 
     \end{table}

     \end{document}
```

Comment: David Carlisle, thanks! Fixed first post. Also, your variant works fine too. But there is a problem, it should be implemented to row individually.

Comment: @МаксКаширный why? you can make every logical row into two actual rows it just means that instead of `&` you use `&&\\[-\normalbaselineskip]&&`  (which you could define to be some command `\zz` then your "row" would be `aaa&bbb\zz ccc&dd\\ ` )

Comment: Ok, I got it! Thanks for explanation, then it will be very nice!