# Vertical alignment in a table

Tags: tables, alignment, vertical

I'm trying to get the vertical alignment for the first column but I'm having some troubles.

Here is a pic of what it looks like right now:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{| >{\bfseries}M{6cm} | L |}
  \hline
  Modulo - Lezione - Unità & Primo - La Scacchiera - Uno \\ \hline
  Numero Pagine &  \\ \hline
  Descrizione & Questa unità mostra qual è la posizione corretta dei pezzi sulla scacchiera. Di seguito la preparazione dello studente verrà verificata mediante appositi esercizi.\\ \hline
  Numero Immagini & \\ \hline
  Numero Video & \\ \hline
  Numero Audio & \\ \hline
  Strumenti di Comunicazione & \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}
```

I've also tried using "m" in the table definition but it still does not work.

[Edit]:
I'm looking for an alignment of the first column in which, for example, the word "Descrizione" is shown in the middle of the box like shown below:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Without [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) and without telling us, which vertical alignment for the first column you expect, it is hard to help. However, maybe you want a `m` column for the second column. Even packages `makecell` and `multirow` could be useful, depending on what the result should be.

Comment: hi @cabohah, thank you! I edited the question for further informations, thanks again

Comment: Still waiting for the minimal working example, and still thinking, you want a `m` or `M` for the second column.

Comment: I added a working example. Anyway I do not understand why you say I want it for the second column, I said for the first column. Anyway I tried with makecell but I should use the command for every row and I was looking for a universal command to define the table.

Comment: No, you've not added a working example but only a code snippet. A working example usually starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Please see the already linked page.

Comment: Why all those rules? They add nothing to clarity. And why should “Descrizione” be in the middle? When you remove the rules, you'll see that a much better position is at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already explained in a comment, you need `m` for the second column not the first one, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand*{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}% use m-columns for X-columns

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\bfseries}c|X|}
  \hline
  Modulo - Lezione - Unità & Primo - La Scacchiera - Uno \\ \hline
  Numero Pagine &  \\ \hline
  Descrizione & Questa unità mostra qual è la posizione corretta dei pezzi sulla scacchiera. Di seguito la preparazione dello studente verrà verificata mediante appositi esercizi.\\ \hline
  Numero Immagini & \\ \hline
  Numero Video & \\ \hline
  Numero Audio & \\ \hline
  Strumenti di Comunicazione & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, might I ask why you need to code the second column to define the first column? I'm new to latex and I'm trying to learn

Comment: @alessandro_pier Because you want align the *middle of the cell of the second column* to the *baseline of the row* not the first one. See also similar questions like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/395356/277964 BTW: Using package `tabularray` could also be useful. And removing all the vertical lines and most of the horizontal could improve the typography. But this would be another question …

Comment: Here's a nice intro: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables . As a beginner, I suggest to scan rather than reading word by word. Try getting the big picture.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a variant of `tabularx` that sets `X` columns with `m`iddle vertical alignment.

But it's better to avoid all those unnecessary rules, see the second realization of the table where

1. the first column has left alignment;
2. there's no padding at either end;
3. there are *no* rules;
4. prepositions have been added and capitalization removed as it's usual in Italian.

You can see that the natural position of “Descrizione” is at the top and I contend it's better also if you insist with caged tables.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for the second solution

\newenvironment{mtabularx}{%
  \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{##1}}\tabularx
}{\endtabularx}

\begin{document}

\section{With rules}

\noindent
\begin{mtabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\bfseries}c|X|}
 \hline
  Modulo - Lezione - Unità & Primo - La Scacchiera - Uno \\ \hline
  Numero Pagine &  \\ \hline
  Descrizione & Questa unità mostra qual è la posizione corretta dei pezzi 
                sulla scacchiera. Di seguito la preparazione dello studente
                verrà verificata mediante appositi esercizi.\\ \hline
  Numero Immagini & \\ \hline
  Numero Video & \\ \hline
  Numero Audio & \\ \hline
  Strumenti di Comunicazione & \\ \hline
\end{mtabularx}

\section{Without unnecessary rules}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}lX@{}}
\toprule
  Modulo - Lezione - Unità & Primo - La Scacchiera - Uno \\
\addlinespace
  Numero di pagine & 17 \\
\addlinespace
  Descrizione & Questa unità mostra qual è la posizione corretta dei pezzi
                sulla scacchiera. Di seguito la preparazione dello studente
                verrà verificata mediante appositi esercizi.\\
\addlinespace
  Numero di immagini & 42 \\
\addlinespace
  Numero dei video & 23 \\
\addlinespace
  Numero degli audio & 12 \\
\addlinespace
  Strumenti di comunicazione & Vattelapesca \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]