# Align text at the bottom + right of the table cell

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, memoir, tabularx, alignment

How do I do [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203428/align-text-at-the-bottom-of-the-table-cell/203481#203481) with the extra twist of getting the text (i.e. my custom page numbering) right aligned?

The end results should look something like this (full width):

```
Text .........    1-2
Text ......... 34-143
Text text text
text tex .....    3-5
```

PS I have tried the obvious setting the cell alignment to `r` but this don't have any real effect.

*(I'm using LuaTex with the document class `memoir`).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have two columns this can be done using `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}`as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{  X r }
    test text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text
  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text\dotfill & 1-2\\
   line test text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text
  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text \dotfill& 34-143\\
   line for comparison \dotfill & 3-5 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to increase the white space between the rows in the table (but not add the full space of a ```\newline```), is that best achieved with ```\vspace{X}``` or does ```tabularx```/```memoir``` ones again come to the rescue with a build-in function for this feature?

Comment: @imdk4242: You can use for example `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` or any other factor of your choice.

Comment: Thanks. So, this is maybe a seperat question but I'll start by posting it here: if I need one more column to the left (right aligned at the top), what do I then do? With the current code example, and adding a column to the left and setting it to ```r```, pushes the text to the bottom right (rather than the top right). Do I need to make an adjustment to the ```\tabularxcolumn``` to make this change happen?

Comment: @imdk4242: Probably related: [Tabular - 3 columns with top-align and bottom-align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447938/134144)

Comment: Partly yes, but this get's us back to the right most column being aligned left and not right (and the table not being full ```\linewidth````). I think this is a separate problem, will post a new question