# 3 columns with top-align and bottom-align [tabularx]

Tags: luatex, memoir, tabularx, columns, alignment

I'm trying to put together a three column table (in `tabularx`) that have the following layout (*in full line width*):

```
Section  Description           Page
    1-5  text text text ......    7
   5-12  text text text text
         text ................  121
```

Note:

- **Left column** is to be top right align
- **Middle column** spans one/multiple lines and ends with a `\dotfill`
- **Right column** is to be bottom-right align

PS: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499963/192642) worked for the middle + right columns, but when I added the left most column, I can't get the text to aligned at the top.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

*(Compiling wit `LuaTex` in document class `memoir`)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon the solution in [Tabular - 3 columns with top-align and bottom-align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447945/134144) I came up with the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}


\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rXr}
Section & Description & Page\\ \addlinespace
        1-5 & 
        test text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text
  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text\dotfill
        &\\[-\normalbaselineskip]&
        &7\\ \addlinespace
        5-12 & 
        test text text  text  text  text  text  text   \dotfill 
        &\\[-\normalbaselineskip]&
        &121\\
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, awesome, thanks

Answer (score 1):

like this?

[image]

With use of the multirow package, where you need manually set the number of lines in the second column:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ r X r }
1-5     &   test text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text\dotfill
            &   \multirow[b]{2}{*}{1-2}  \\
5-12    &   test text text text text text text text text text text test text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text\dotfill
            &   \multirow[b]{3}{*}{34-143}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Correct. However, I need to change the index manually each time (in above MWE: ```2``` for first row and ```3``` for second row) as I go along? This can show to be problematic if the paper size is changed etc. Is there a way of getting the same result with the right most column aligning bottom without manually inputing for each row?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{collcell}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{B}{>{\collectcell{\Block[B]{}}}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{rXB}
Section & Description & Page\\[1mm]
        1-5 & 
        test text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text
  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text\dotfill
        & 7 \\[1mm]
        5-12 & 
        test text text  text  text  text  text  text   \dotfill 
        & 121 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]