# Vertical alignment of text and figures in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I am trying to put together a table with both images and text, but I keep having problems to get the vertical alignment right. Ideally I would like to have both the text and images in the centre of the cells.

My original code is:

```
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline   
    \textbf{Approach} & \textbf{Pure translation} & \textbf{120\degree bend} & \textbf{135\degree twist} & \textbf{70\degree bend} \\
\hline 
Original & \includegraphics[scale=0.1] {figure1.jpg} & \includegraphics[scale=0.1] {figure1.jpg} & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Hello}
\end{table}
```

Which gives me this result:

[image]

I have tried using \raisebox like this:

```
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c |}
\hline   
    \textbf{Approach} & \textbf{Pure translation} & \textbf{120\degree bend} & \textbf{135\degree twist} & \textbf{70\degree bend} \\
\hline 
Original & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1] {figure1.jpg}} & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1] {figure2.jpg}} & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Hello}
\end{table}
```

But the result is still not satisfactory:

[image]

Using a `\parbox` for the text column doesn't do the trick either...

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19080/15925

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You raised by `\totalheight` but you want center so use `.5\totalheight`  actually you may want a bit less as that puts the baseline in the centre and then the text will sit on that baseline so might nook a bit high, but you can lower the text with `\raisebox` around `Original` with a value around `0.5\baselineskip` or whatever looks right, fine tuning requires visual perception of the shape of the image and of the letters...