# Vertical alignment in a tabular environment with asymptote image

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, asymptote

In a tabular environment, I would like to align text vertically at the top of one cell while placing an Asymptote image in an adjacent cell.  There are numerous posts on vertical alignment with images in a tabular environment with "normal" image placement using \includegraphics.  See here for instance:

[Vertical alignment of text and figures in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116520/vertical-alignment-of-text-and-figures-in-a-table)

However, the two most commonly suggested techniques -- using \raisebox or \adjustbox -- don't seem to work with asymptote images.  Here is a minimal example showing the effect I would like to get, and what actually happens when I use an asymptote image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
Text &
\raisebox{-.9\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}}

\\ Text &
\begin{asy}
import graph;
unitsize(1inch);
draw((0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--(0,0));
\end{asy}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Any idea how to get top-aligned text next to an asymptote image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `adjustbox` it's really easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
Text &
  \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}} \\
Text &
  \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
  \begin{asy}
  import graph;
  unitsize(1inch);
  draw((0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--(0,0));
  \end{asy}
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I used the “command form” in the first case, because it's handier. Around the `asy` environment it's better instead using the “environment form”.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I was only aware of the \adjustbox command form, not the environment form.  That makes all the difference!