# Need to align text to top of cell in table

Tags: tables, multirow, wrap

this is the code I have now:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|p{8cm}|}
\hline
NB & Screen & Description\\
\hline
\multirow{-40}{*}{1}
&
\includegraphics[scale=0.4, trim=0 0 0 -5]{CO600_Screenshots/Login-Accounts}
&
The first view is the Google Login Screen and has 4 buttons. \newline Selecting either
of the accounts will take us to Screen 2, 'Add Account' and 'Remove' will take us to
further Google screens which have not been documented.
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

The large block of text after the \includegraphics is placed automatically at the bottom of the cell - I need to place it at the top.

I've tried to use the multirow package to do this but then the text extends out of the cell and stops wrapping.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19080/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-an-image-in-the-same-row-of-a-table and related questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `\raisebox`. I loaded the `cellspace` package t to ensure a minimal spacing between the contents of cells and the above and below horizontal lines. The `1.5ex` that intervenes in `\raisebox` is an adjustment approximately corresponds to the height of capitals letters in the current font, so that the top of the image is aligned with the top of a capital letter, and not with the base line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\renewcommand\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\renewcommand\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|Sl|S{p{8cm}}|}
\hline
NB & Screen & Description\\
\hline
1
&
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height + 1.5ex\relax}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4, trim=0 0 0 -5]{CO600_Screenshots/Login-Accounts}}
&
The first view is the Google Login Screen and has 4 buttons. \newline Selecting either
of the accounts will take us to Screen 2, 'Add Account' and 'Remove' will take us to
further Google screens which have not been documented.
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]