# Text next to an xskak diagram?

Tags: tables, xskak

The `\chessboard` command from `xskak.sty` assembles the board using glyphs from a chess font.  This causes me a *ton* of headaches trying put explanatory text next to a board.

The first and most obvious attempt was to use a table (actually I have multiple diagrams in a table with 3 boards and associated text per line, but it would be nice to get just one diagram to work for now.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{tabular}{l p{4cm}}
\chessboard[setfen=] &
White to move.  Mutual zugzwang.
\end{tabular}\par}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the text goes on the baseline in the second column and it looks... well... like shit. I would prefer to have it stick to the top of the diagram or be centred.

I.e.:

```
r n b q k b n r    Text should be 
p p p p p p p p    aligned like this
. . . . . . . .    in the final PDF.
. . . . . . . .                          Or centred
. . . . . . . .                          vertically.
. . . . . . . . 
P P P P P P P P 
R N B Q K B N R                                        It should
                                                       definitely not
                                                       be aligned with
                                                       the baseline of 
                                                       the diagram.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has absolutly nothing to do with the way the chessboard is build. The chessboard is like e.g. a graphic simply a box with the baseline at the bottom and so allmost all answers concerning the alignment of graphics with text (see e.g. [How to vertically center text with an image in the same row of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19080/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-an-image-in-the-same-row-of-a-table/)) can be used in this case too: You can use `\raisebox` or e.g. adjustbox:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak,adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l p{4cm}}
\adjustbox{valign=c}{\chessboard[setfen=]} &
White to move.  Mutual zugzwang.
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It even worked with `array.sty` and `>{\adjustbox{valign=c}\bgroup}l<{\egroup}` so I didn't have to write it every line.

Comment: Even better: `>{\adjustbox{valign=t,raise=\adjboxvtop}\bgroup}l<{\egroup}` which makes the text aligned with the top of the diagram such that the baseline matches the line between the 7th and 8th ranks.