# How do I put two figures side by side at the entrylist of the Friggeri-CV template?

Tags: templates, cv, friggeri-cv

Take a look to the pictures below:

[image]

This is the code I have:

```
\entry

{2017}

{Certificado SolidWorks {\normalfont [nível Associate]}}

{\includegraphics[width=15mm]{CSWA.png}}{\includegraphics[width=15mm]{CSWA.png}}

{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
```

Here it is the entire code:

```
% -- Encoding UTF-8 without BOM

% -- XeLaTeX => PDF (BIBER)
\documentclass[]{cv-style}          

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 

\usepackage{tikz} 

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, latexsym}

\sethyphenation[variant=british]{english}{} 

\begin{document}

\header{José Pedro }{Amorim}           

\begin{aside}

%ASD

\end{aside}

\section{formação complementar}

{\vspace{-1.2cm}}

\begin{entrylist}

\entry

{2017}

{Certificado SolidWorks {\normalfont [nível Associate]}}

{\includegraphics[width=15mm]{CSWA.png}}{\includegraphics[width=15mm]{CSWA.png}}

{\vspace{-0.3cm}}

\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do never post code as image. It would be very nice, if you could provide us with a full MWE to help us help you.

Comment: Please post a compilable document, not just fragments

Answer (score 1):

You are simply misusing the template. (most  likely [this one](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/friggeri-cv-template/hmnchbfmjgqh#.WQ3ASjQlH4g))

Both pictures need to be added within the same pair of braces.

[image: asdFrigerri]

```
% -- Encoding UTF-8 without BOM
% -- XeLaTeX => PDF (BIBER)

\documentclass[]{cv-style}          % Add 'print' as an option into the square bracket to remove colours from this template for printing. 
                                    % Add 'espanol' as an option into the square bracket to change the date format of the Last Updated Text

\sethyphenation[variant=british]{english}{} % Add words between the {} to avoid them to be cut 

\begin{document}

\header{John}{Smith}           % Your name
\lastupdated

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION  -- In the aside, each new line forces a line break
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{aside}
%
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 050022
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
john@smith.com
%
\section{languages}
English mother tongue
Spanish fluency
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
\end{aside}


\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
    \entry
    {2017}
    {Certificado Duck {\normalfont [nível Associate]}}
    {%
        \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image-1x1.png}
        \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image-1x1.png}
    }
    {\vspace{-1\baselineskip}}
    \entry
    {2017}
    {Certificado Capybara {\normalfont [nível Associate]}}
    {%
        \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image-1x1.png}
        \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image-1x1.png}
    }
    {\vspace{-1\baselineskip}}
\entry
  {2014--Now}
  {COMPANY 3}
  {City, Country}
  {\jobtitle{Wombat}\\
  Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description.}
\end{entrylist}


\end{document}
```

---

Adrien did not put a suitable license for his class in the past. It has been ripped off by many individuals, the license did allow this. For a long time, the original template repository has been deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine :)
Is there an option to align the figures with the text?

Comment: @ASD They are aligned on the base line  of the text.

Comment: But how do I align by the center of the text with the center of the image?

Comment: @ASD [How to vertically center text with an image in the same row of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19080/37907)