# How to align content in all cells in table with images vertically to center

Tags: tables, graphics

I am quite beginner with LaTeX. I am trying to make one table with 3 columns, where the second column contains images. The rest contains just simple text. My problem is to synchronize contents (text and images) in all cells. I want to align contents vertically to center in all cells.

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{4}
%\setlength\extrarowheight{25pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|l|}
\hline
Continue   &    \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25] 
{Figures/Udalosti/eventContinue.png}}&test\\
\hline
Born        & \includegraphics[scale=0.25] 
{Figures/Udalosti/eventBorn.png}&test\\
\hline
Death       & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Figures/Udalosti/eventDeath.png}&test \\
\hline
Merge       & \includegraphics[scale=0.20]{Figures/Udalosti/eventMerge.png}&test\\
\hline
Split       & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Figures/Udalosti/eventSplit.png} &test \\
\hline
Growth & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Figures/Udalosti/eventGrowth.png} &test \\
\hline
Contraction & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Figures/Udalosti/eventContraction.png} &test \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{Test}
\label{tab_evolution}
\end{table}
```

[image]

The result is here on the picture. I tried to align contents vertically with raisebox in first row, but as you can see, it doesn't work properly. Text in first and third column is vertically aligned on center but pictures in second column are not. Can you help me? I would be very grateful for any question. Thank you. :)

Comment: Did you check the answers to this question? [How to vertically center text with an image in the same row of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19080/134144)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try loading `adjustbox`, which extends `graphicx` and using `\adjincludegraphics[scale=0.25, valign=c]{graphic file}`.

Comment: I recently had a similar issue, I used `tablular` with the column type`m` for the image column and it looks fine.