# Centering images and text in a table without specified dimensions

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a table with images and text and I want to align them to the centre of the cells they're in. Most questions like this one have answers which first fix the cell size and then centre its contents.

How can I do this without having to fix the dimensions of the cell and just align contents of every cell to its centre (I'm specifically referring to vertical alignment since horizontal alignment is taken care of by `|c|c|...`)

```
 \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}

    \hline \includegraphics[height=1in]{IMG1.jpg} & 1 & 2 & 2 kHz & 1 kHz \\

    \hline \includegraphics[height=1in]{IMG2.jpg} & 1 & 3 & 3 kHz & 1 kHz \\

    \hline \includegraphics[height=1in]{IMG3.jpg} & 2 & 5 & 5 kHz & 2 kHz \\

    \hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{random caption}

\end{table}
```

This is what the code for my table looks like. The only problem is, in every cell, the image is vertically aligned to the top and the text is vertically aligned to the bottom. How can I fix this?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! to clarify what is your problem, please provide an example of your table in complete but small document beginning with`\documentclass{...}`and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Just like you said, I've added the code

Comment: Related:[How to vertically center text with an image in the same row of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19080/134144).

Comment: Doing that didn't align the image vertically to the centre of the cell.

Comment: @TEC0001: What exactly does 'that' refer to? The question I linked to contains four answers with different approaches. As one can see in [Ignasi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199644/134144), the `valign`/`align` option from either the `adjustbox` od the `graphbox` package will lead to vertically centered texts and images.

Comment: this is not complete document ... it started with `\documentclass{...}`  and ending with `\end{document}`. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you looking for something like this:

[image]

a complete small document (called mwe: minimal working example), is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[export, demo]{adjustbox} % it also load "graphicx"
                                     % in real document delete option "demo"
\usepackage{siunitx}                 % added for used units

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline 
\includegraphics[height=1in, valign=c, margin=0pt 6pt 0pt 6pt]{IMG1.jpg} & 1 & 2 & \SI{2}{kHz} & \SI{1}{kHz} \\
\hline 
\includegraphics[height=1in, valign=c, margin=0pt 6pt 0pt 6pt]{IMG2.jpg} & 1 & 3 & \SI{3}{kHz} & \SI{1}{kHz} \\
\hline 
\includegraphics[height=1in, valign=c, margin=0pt 6pt 0pt 6pt]{IMG3.jpg} & 2 & 5 & \SI{5}{kHz} & \SI{2}{kHz} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

table code as well necessary preamble should be simple to transfer in your real document.