# How can I align the text with an image in a tabularx?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

So I have this table with an image and a table

```
\cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
\bgroup
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}c@{}X}
  \includegraphics[width=1.02in]{img/uaqlogo.eps} &
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
    \LARGE Universidad Autónoma de Querétaro \\[0.15in]
    \Large Facultad de Ingeniería \\[0.15in]
    \large Maestría en Ciencias en Inteligencia Artificial
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
```

That produces this:

[image: Alignment]

Is there a way to align it horizontally? I dont know why they are using b, whenever I use h or t it moves the text even lower.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please make a) make your code compilable (See: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) and b) clarify on the desired alignment? Do you want centered, top or bottom alignment?

Comment: The solution presented here might be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199644/134144

Comment: Another possibility is the `adjustbox` package: `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` in the preamble, `\includegraphics[valign=t]{...}` in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is, with `adjustbox` and  a local definition of the `X` columntype. Note that beforehand, I converted the logo to .pdf with the `epspdf` utility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\bgroup
 \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}c@{}X}
 \includegraphics[width=1.02in, valign=c]{uaqlogo} &
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
    \LARGE Universidad Autónoma de Querétaro \\[0.15in]
    \Large Facultad de Ingeniería \\[0.15in]
    \large Maestría en Ciencias en Inteligencia Artificial
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `tabularx`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont % Helvetica
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\includegraphics[width=1.02in]{uaqlogo}
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\LARGE Universidad Autónoma de Querétaro \\[0.15in]
\Large Facultad de Ingeniería \\[0.15in]
\large Maestría en Ciencias en Inteligencia Artificial
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]