# How to center title including figure vertically in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, titles, alignment

I started using rather large Beamer-based template. Everything is good except title vertical align - for default font size it looks ok:

[image]

But when I change the fontsize to, e.g. `9pt` like this:

```
\documentclass[lualatex,hyperref={pdfencoding=auto},9pt]{beamer}
```

The gets shifted upwards

[image]

As far as I found out, the vertical alignment is set up with this code:

```
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
    {   
        \nointerlineskip
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=1.8em,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
            \vbox{}\vskip-2ex
            \strut\insertframetitle\strut
            \hfill
            \raisebox{-0.25\height}{\includegraphics[height=1.35em]{\proj@TightSignFileName}}
            \vskip-0.8ex%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
```

Is there any way, how to do the vertical alignment "dynamically", so that the whole title would be positioned in the middle, no matter the font size?

I've tried `valign` from `adjustbox` package as mentioned in [How to vertically center text with an image in the same row of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19080/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-an-image-in-the-same-row-of-a-table) , but it doesn't seem to work really well in this case:

[image]

```
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
    {   
        \nointerlineskip
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=1.8em,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
            \vbox{}\vskip-2ex
            \strut\insertframetitle\strut
            \hfill
            \includegraphics[valign=m,height=1.35em]{\vsb@TightSignFileName}
            \vskip-0.8ex%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
```

---

#### Download link

Due to the large number of necessary files and images I uploaded complete MWE onto this link:

https://gofile.io/?c=2d0D8O

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @AndréC The whole template is divided into several pretty long codes, but I'll try to choose the necessary ones and upload them here.

Comment: @AndréC I uploaded minimalized version to the permanent link added into the question - I was not able to remove all the dependencies now and putting all the code here would be confusing, I believe.

Comment: Note that we generally do not like following external links as they tend to rot over time and thus your example is unusable for others in the future.

Comment: @daleif I'm aware of that - I'll try to improve this one over time.

Comment: The site on which the zip file is stored is written in Czech. Placing this file on an English-speaking site is preferable.

Comment: @AndréC thank you, uploaded to gofile.io now.

Answer (score 0):

You could bracket your code in:

```
\vspace*{\fill}
  % Your stuff here
\vspace*{\fill}
```

This adds vertical space (`\vspace`) unconditionally (`*`), the space to be added is "as long as will fit" (`\fill`). Both `\fill` fight for space, each gets half. If you want uneven space top/bottom, use `\stretch{n}`:

```
\vspace*{\stretch{2}}
  % Your stuff here
\vspace*{\stretch{3}}
```

This will give 2/5 of the space above. Can use the same idea horizontally, BTW.

Comment: It seems, that `\vspace` gets completely ignored. On the other hand, `\vskip` still has effect..