# Fix the numbering in exam class with minipage

Tags: minipage, exam

I am trying to put the figure beside the text in exam class using `\minipage`. The best I can do currently is as the following:

[image]

With the MWE:

```
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.9cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{longfbox}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem, tasks}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[justify]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{fancybox,framed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\captionsetup[table]{name=表格}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{mynewdots}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{1pt}}% original definition: \pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}
{%
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{.5pt}%
    \pgfusepath{fill}%
}%

% A custom arrowhead for use on x, y, z axes
\tikzstyle{axisarrow} = [-{Latex[inset=0pt,length=5pt]}]

\tikzset{
    slope/.code={\edef\slope{#1}},
    slope/.default=0.5,
    slope
}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\tikz@pattern@color,\slope]{slant lines}
{\pgfpoint{-.1mm/\slope}{-.1mm}}
{\pgfpoint{1.1mm/\slope}{1.1mm}}
{\pgfpoint{1mm/\slope}{1mm}}
{
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.1mm/\slope}{-.1mm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.1mm/\slope}{1.1mm}}
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother

\lfoot{$\copyright$ 2013循人中学版权所有}
\rfoot{【机密】}
\cfoot{- \thepage \, - }
\newtcolorbox{tcbdoublebox}[1][]{%
    enhanced jigsaw,
    sharp corners,
    hbox,
    colback=white,
    borderline={1pt}{-2pt}{black},
    fontupper={\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}},
    #1
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=Hei,ItalicFont=Kai]{KaiTi}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage[font=normal,justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{\textbf \thechoice \, \,}
\newenvironment{solutions}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{15pt}%
}

\newcommand{\ihat}{\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}}
\newcommand{\jhat}{\boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}}
\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\!/\mkern-5mu/\!}}


\newcommand\afterclasspart{\renewcommand\partlabel{(\thepartno)\makebox[0pt]{$\ ^\ast$}}}  
\newcommand\standardpart{\renewcommand\partlabel{(\thepartno)}}

\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
    \settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 0em}
}
\settasks{label={\Alph*}, label-format=\bfseries, label-offset = 1em, column-sep = 1.5em, item-indent=2em}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\choices}{\penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax}{\hfill}{}{}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\unframedsolutions

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{tipa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{tipa}{m}{n}{<->tipa10}{}
\newcommand{\arc@char}{{\usefont{U}{tipa}{m}{n}\symbol{62}}}%

\renewcommand{\arc}[1]{\mathpalette\arc@arc{#1}}

\newcommand{\arc@arc}[2]{%
    \sbox0{$\m@th#1#2$}%
    \vbox{
        \hbox{\resizebox{\wd0}{\height}{\arc@char}}
        \nointerlineskip
        \box0
    }%
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
    hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
    hatch distance=10pt,
    hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
    hatch thickness=2pt
}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
{\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
    % style to apply some styles to each segment of a path
    on each segment/.style={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            show path construction,
            moveto code={},
            lineto code={
                \path [#1]
                (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
            curveto code={
                \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
                .. controls
                (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
                ..
                (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
            closepath code={
                \path [#1]
                (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
        },
    },
    % style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
    mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}
    }}},
    midd arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[thick,blue]{#1}}
    }}},
}
\pgfarrowsdeclaredouble{<<s}{>>s}{stealth}{stealth}%   double stealth


\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{2.5cm}
        \pointsdroppedatright
        \marginpointname{\%}
        \bigskip
        \question 
        \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
            \question 
        \begin{parts}
            \part Figure 1 shows a pyramid $ABCD-E$. Suppose that $AE=13$, $AC=10$. Find the followings:
            \begin{subparts}
                \subpart[1] Height $ME$.\droppoints
                \subpart[2] Area of base square $ABCD$.\droppoints 
                \subpart[2] Volume of pyramid $ABCD-E$.\droppoints 
            \end{subparts}
            \bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
            \part[5] As shown in Figure 2，The horizontal distance between building P and Q are $BC=30$ meters. The angle of elevation from point $A$ to point $C$ and to point $D$ are $45^\circ$ and $30^\circ$, respectively. If these two building are perpendicular to the ground, find their vertical height. \droppoints 
            \end{parts}
        \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}{0.03\textwidth}
            \textcolor{white}{hello}
        \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \raisebox{-7cm}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
            \def\raio{1.5}
            \def\altura{3}
            \def\marca{0.2}
            \def\ang{68}
            \draw[thick] (-\raio,0,\raio) -- (\raio,0,\raio) -- (\raio,0,-\raio);
            \draw[thick, densely dashed,black!80] (\raio,0,-\raio) -- (-\raio,0,-\raio) -- (-\raio,0,\raio);
            \node[left] at (-\raio,0,\raio) {$A$};
            \node[right] at (\raio,0,\raio) {$B$};
            \node[right] at (\raio-0.1,0,-\raio) {$C$};
            \node[above] at (-\raio-0.2,-0.15,-\raio+0.2) {$D$};
            \node[above] at (0,\altura-0.1,0) {$E$};
            \node[below] at (0,0,0) {$M$};
            \draw (-\marca,0,-\marca) -- (\marca,0,\marca);
            \draw (\marca,0,-\marca) -- (-\marca,0,\marca);
            \draw[densely dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,\altura,0);
            \draw[thick] (-\raio,0,\raio) -- (0,\altura,0) -- (\raio,0,-\raio);
            \draw[thick] (\raio,0,\raio) -- (0,\altura,0);
            \draw[thick, densely dashed,black!80] (0,\altura,0) -- (-\raio,0,-\raio);
            \node at (0.3,-1.05,1.25){Figure 1};        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
            \raisebox{-1cm}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9,
            one end extended/.style={shorten <=-#1},
            one end extended/.default=1.5cm,
            my angle/.style={
                every pic quotes/.append style={text=black},
                draw=black!200,
                thick,
                fill=orange!20,
                angle radius=0.6cm,
            }]
            %\tkzGrid
            \tkzDefPoints{4/1/B, 1.8/1/C, 7.2/1/D, 7.2/0.8/F}
            \tkzDefShiftPoint[B](135:4){A};
            \tkzDrawSegment[very thick](C,D);
            \draw [fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none] (C) rectangle (F);
            \draw[thick, pattern=mynewdots, pattern color=purple!40] (2,1) rectangle (3,4.5);
            \draw[thick, pattern=mynewdots, pattern color=green] (6,1) rectangle (7,2.5);
            \coordinate (G) at (3,4.5);
            \coordinate (H) at (6,2.5);
            \coordinate (I) at (3,1);
            \coordinate (J) at (6,1);
            \coordinate (K) at (3.7,2.5);
            \coordinate (L) at (5,4.5);
            \node at (G) [above]{$A$};
            \node at (3,0.9) [below]{$B$};
            \node at (6,0.9) [below]{$C$};
            \node at (6.2,2.5) [above=-2.5pt]{$D$};
            \node at (2.5,2.75) {P};
            \node at (6.5,1.75) {Q};
            \draw[dashed] (G)--(H);
            \draw[dashed](G)--(6,1);
            \draw[dashed] (G)--(5,4.5);
            \pic [my angle, anchor=west, "$45^\circ$", angle eccentricity=1, thick, fill opacity=0.2, angle radius=1.3cm, fill=blue!40, text opacity=1] {angle=J--G--L};
            \pic [my angle, anchor=west, "$30^\circ$", angle eccentricity=1, thick] {angle=H--G--L};
            \node at (4.5,0) {Figure 2};
            \draw[dashed] (G)--(H);
            \draw[dashed](G)--(6,1);
            \draw[dashed] (G)--(5,4.5);
            \tkzDrawSegment[very thick](C,D);
            \end{tikzpicture}}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

You can see that in order to put numbering beside `\part`, I have forced to put two `\question` commands, so that one in the beginning and one in the middle. I hope the middle one could disappear, and whose numbered with '2' can be returned to '1'. On the other hand, I could not figure out any code syntax so that my `tikzpicture` can be well located at the right of each subquestion. I have to adjust many times, using `\raisebox` to each minipage -- This is quite inefficient especially I need to deal with many questions.

Is there any ways to solve my question? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that exam class uses lists which expect a constant width, especially to print points.  OTOH, you can use paracol to put figures into a separate column and sync them up.

To change the width you could save all the counters to global macros (e.g. `\xdef\lastquestion{\number{question}}`), end all the environments including paracol, then restart them all using the saved counter values (e.g. `\setcounter{question}{\lastquestion}`)

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.9cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{paracol}
\setcolumnwidth{0.65\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \begin{questions}
        \setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{2.5cm}
        \pointsdroppedatright
        \marginpointname{\%}
        \bigskip
        \question 
        \begin{parts}
            \part Figure \ref{test1} shows a pyramid $ABCD-E$. Suppose that $AE=13$, $AC=10$. Find the followings:
            \begin{subparts}
                \subpart[1] Height $ME$.\droppoints
                \subpart[2] Area of base square $ABCD$.\droppoints 
                \subpart[2] Volume of pyramid $ABCD-E$.\droppoints 
            \end{subparts}
        \switchcolumn
            \begin{figure}[ht]
              \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
              \caption{}\label{test1}
            \end{figure}
        \switchcolumn*
            \part[5] As shown in Figure \ref{test2} ... If these two building are perpendicular to the ground, find their vertical height. \droppoints 
        \switchcolumn
            \begin{figure}[ht]
              \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
              \caption{}\label{test2}
            \end{figure}
        \switchcolumn*
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: What if I have a question, says (a) with figure, and (b) is just plain text and no figure to get consistently sync so that (a) has 2 columns and (b) only has 1 column? I would like to have text for subquestion (b) on the space where figure 2 occupied.

Comment: You can use `\switchcolumn` instead of `\switchcolum*` to NOT synchronize columns. You can even use `\switchcolumn[0]*` to synchronize columns while staying in the first column.

Comment: If you want to use the right column for text, that falls into the same category as changing the width.  Painful, but doable.

Comment: I am sorry but what do you technically mean by "synchronize columns"?

Comment: And is there a difference in using minipage or paracol?

Comment: May I know how make `paracol` have the same output of `tabular` in [this document](https://pastebin.com/vPi9FcGa) since the first column is a bit wider than that of `tabular`.

Comment: Sorry, been busy.  Synchronizing columns means that nothing new appears above the current lowest position in any column.  The main difference between a minipage and paracol is that you can easily switch back and forth between the columns.  OTOH, if you intend to change the width each time. using minipages and paracol would be equally difficult.

Comment: On second thought, using paracol to change widths would be more difficult.

Comment: I apologize but I didn't understand how to remove tabular margin inside the list of subpart? I would be grateful if you could show me how to do it by editing the document I put its link before.

Comment: You remove or change tabular margins using `@{}` or `@{\hspace{...}}` in the columns argument.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workabout for what you want.

Your problem comes from the `minipage` environment. By default, its alignment is centered on the baseline, but you could change this alignment using the optional argument of `minipage`. `\begin{minipage}[align]{width}`. The align could be `t` for top, `c` for center or `b` for bottom.

I put the minipage inside the `\part`and made one line for every part.  It'll be easier to align a picture with the corresponding text.

You need to define the baseline of your tikzpicture. By default, it is consider as a big caracter with the baseline at the bottom. There is a key that you could use, as an optional argument to the environment. `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(some node)]`

Then, every part will look like this:

```
\part \begin{minipage}[t]{width}
Your text here
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{width}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(...)]
your picture here
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
```

Starting from your code, here is my solution. I used two different nodes to align the pictures, to show different possibilities.

```
\documentclass[draft]{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.9cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{mynewdots}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{1pt}}% original definition: \pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}
{%
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{.5pt}%
    \pgfusepath{fill}%
}%

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{2.5cm}
        \pointsdroppedatright
        \marginpointname{\%}
        \question 
        \begin{parts}
            \part 
       \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
 Figure 1 shows a pyramid $ABCD-E$. Suppose that $AE=13$, $AC=10$. Find the followings:
            \begin{subparts}
                \subpart[1] Height $ME$.\droppoints
                \subpart[2] Area of base square $ABCD$.\droppoints 
                \subpart[2] Volume of pyramid $ABCD-E$.\droppoints 
            \end{subparts}
        \end{minipage}
          \hfill
           \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9,baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
            \def\raio{1.5}
            \def\altura{3}
            \def\marca{0.2}
            \def\ang{68}
            \draw[thick] (-\raio,0,\raio) -- (\raio,0,\raio) -- (\raio,0,-\raio);
            \draw[thick, densely dashed,black!80] (\raio,0,-\raio) -- (-\raio,0,-\raio) -- (-\raio,0,\raio);
            \node[left] at (-\raio,0,\raio) {$A$};
            \node[right] at (\raio,0,\raio) {$B$};
            \node[right] at (\raio-0.1,0,-\raio) {$C$};
            \node[above] at (-\raio-0.2,-0.15,-\raio+0.2) {$D$};
            \node[above] at (0,\altura-0.1,0) {$E$};
            \node[below] at (0,0,0) {$M$};
            \draw (-\marca,0,-\marca) -- (\marca,0,\marca);
            \draw (\marca,0,-\marca) -- (-\marca,0,\marca);
            \draw[densely dashed] (0,0,0) -- (0,\altura,0);
            \draw[thick] (-\raio,0,\raio) -- (0,\altura,0) -- (\raio,0,-\raio);
            \draw[thick] (\raio,0,\raio) -- (0,\altura,0);
            \draw[thick, densely dashed,black!80] (0,\altura,0) -- (-\raio,0,-\raio);
            \node at (0.3,-1.05,1.25){Figure 1};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
%            \bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
            \part[5] 
       \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
As shown in Figure 2，The horizontal distance between building P and Q are $BC=30$ meters. The angle of elevation from point $A$ to point $C$ and to point $D$ are $45^\circ$ and $30^\circ$, respectively. If these two building are perpendicular to the ground, find their vertical height. \droppoints 
        \end{minipage}
           \hfill
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\linewidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9,
            one end extended/.style={shorten <=-#1},
            one end extended/.default=1.5cm,
            my angle/.style={
                every pic quotes/.append style={text=black},
                draw=black!200,
                thick,
                fill=orange!20,
                angle radius=0.6cm,
            },
            baseline=(G)]
            %\tkzGrid
            \tkzDefPoints{4/1/B, 1.8/1/C, 7.2/1/D, 7.2/0.8/F}
            \tkzDefShiftPoint[B](135:4){A};
            \tkzDrawSegment[very thick](C,D);
            \draw [fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none] (C) rectangle (F);
            \draw[thick, pattern=mynewdots, pattern color=purple!40] (2,1) rectangle (3,4.5);
            \draw[thick, pattern=mynewdots, pattern color=green] (6,1) rectangle (7,2.5);
            \coordinate (G) at (3,4.5);
            \coordinate (H) at (6,2.5);
            \coordinate (I) at (3,1);
            \coordinate (J) at (6,1);
            \coordinate (K) at (3.7,2.5);
            \coordinate (L) at (5,4.5);
            \node at (G) [above]{$A$};
            \node at (3,0.9) [below]{$B$};
            \node at (6,0.9) [below]{$C$};
            \node at (6.2,2.5) [above=-2.5pt]{$D$};
            \node at (2.5,2.75) {P};
            \node at (6.5,1.75) {Q};
            \draw[dashed] (G)--(H);
            \draw[dashed](G)--(6,1);
            \draw[dashed] (G)--(5,4.5);
            \pic [my angle, anchor=west, "$45^\circ$", angle eccentricity=1, thick, fill opacity=0.2, angle radius=1.3cm, fill=blue!40, text opacity=1] {angle=J--G--L};
            \pic [my angle, anchor=west, "$30^\circ$", angle eccentricity=1, thick] {angle=H--G--L};
            \node at (4.5,0) {Figure 2};
            \draw[dashed] (G)--(H);
            \draw[dashed](G)--(6,1);
            \draw[dashed] (G)--(5,4.5);
            \tkzDrawSegment[very thick](C,D);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
            \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Not relevant to the problem, but there are some mistakes in your code.  Some packages are loaded twice (graphicx, tcolorbox, caption).

When doing minipage like this, make sure you didn't exceed the text width. In your code, you have 0.65+0.03+0.40=1.08. This causes an overfull hbox to every line.

Also, when providing a code sample to show the problem, try to make it as small as possible by removing unnecessary package and command. It reduces the risk of compatibility issues. In your example, half the code wasn't useful to the problem and could have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tabular` and `adjustbox` with the code of John Kormylo's answer, you can get the same output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.9cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % <-- it loads graphicx and provides the key 'valign'
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{2.5cm}
        \pointsdroppedatright
        \marginpointname{\%}
        \bigskip
        \question 
        \begin{parts}
            \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
            \part
            \begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.65\linewidth}@{\hspace{0.01\linewidth}}p{0.34\linewidth}}
                Figure \ref{test1} shows a pyramid $ABCD-E$. Suppose that $AE=13$, $AC=10$. Find the followings:
                \begin{subparts}
                    \subpart[1] Height $ME$.\droppoints
                    \subpart[2] Area of base square $ABCD$.\droppoints 
                    \subpart[2] Volume of pyramid $ABCD-E$.\droppoints 
                \end{subparts} & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{example-image-a}
            \captionof{figure}{}\label{test1}
            \end{tabular}
        
            \part[5]
            \begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.65\linewidth}@{\hspace{0.01\linewidth}}p{0.34\linewidth}}
            As shown in Figure \ref{test2} ... If these two building are perpendicular to the ground, find their vertical height. \droppoints 
            & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{example-image-b}
            \captionof{figure}{}\label{test2}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```