# exam: two-column questions

Tags: tables, minipage, exam, paracol

Following-up [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/564720/2288) and considering the two-column MWE below, I would like to

1- understand why the inter-line spacing inside `minipage` is bigger than that of both `tabular` and `paracol`

2- know what is missing for `paracol` to make it have the same question layout (column width and figure vertical alignment) of the first two approaches of `tabular` and `minipage`

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.9cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,paracol}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\setcolumnwidth{0.65\linewidth,0.34\linewidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{2.5cm}
        \pointsdroppedatright
        \marginpointname{\%}
        \bigskip
        \question
        \begin{parts}
            \part
            \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
            \begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.65\linewidth}@{\hspace{0.01\linewidth}}p{0.34\linewidth}}
                Figure \ref{test1} shows a pyramid $ABCD-E$. Suppose that $AE=13$, $AC=10$. Find the followings:
                \begin{subparts}
                    \subpart[1] Height $ME$.\droppoints
                    \subpart[2] Area of base square $ABCD$.\droppoints
                    \subpart[2] Volume of pyramid $ABCD-E$.\droppoints
                \end{subparts} & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,align=t]{example-image-a}
                \captionof{figure}{tabular approach}\label{test1}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{parts}
        %
        \question
        \begin{parts}
            \part
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
                Figure \ref{test3} shows a pyramid $ABCD-E$. Suppose that $AE=13$, $AC=10$. Find the followings:
                \begin{subparts}
                    \subpart[1] Height $ME$.\droppoints
                    \subpart[2] Area of base square $ABCD$.\droppoints
                    \subpart[2] Volume of pyramid $ABCD-E$.\droppoints
                \end{subparts}
            \end{minipage}%
            \hfill
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.34\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,align=t]{example-image-b}
                \captionof{figure}{minipage approach}\label{test3}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{parts}
        %
        \question
        \begin{parts}
            \part
            \begin{paracol}{2} 
                Figure \ref{test2} shows a pyramid $ABCD-E$. Suppose that $AE=13$, $AC=10$. Find the followings:
                \begin{subparts}
                    \subpart[1] Height $ME$.\droppoints
                    \subpart[2] Area of base square $ABCD$.\droppoints
                    \subpart[2] Volume of pyramid $ABCD-E$.\droppoints
                \end{subparts}
                \switchcolumn
                \begin{figure}[ht]
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
                    \caption{paracol approach}\label{test2}
                \end{figure}
            \end{paracol}
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both \itemsep and \parskip take on different values in the three examples, with the change occurring in \begin{subparts}. This does not occur when using a \parbox instead, but \@minipagefalse does not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both \itemsep and \parskip take on different values in the three examples, with the change occurring in \begin{subparts}. This does not occur when using a \parbox instead.  Nor can I find the code responsible for the change.

I included the following to try to equalize both the horizontal and vertical spacing for the three solutions.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.9cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2.2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,paracol}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\columnsep=0.01\textwidth

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{2.5cm}
        \pointsdroppedatright
        \marginpointname{\%}
        \bigskip
        \question
        \begin{parts}
            \part
            \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
            \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.65\linewidth}@{\hspace{\columnsep}}p{0.34\linewidth}@{}}
                Figure \ref{test1} shows a pyramid $ABCD-E$. Suppose that $AE=13$, $AC=10$. Find the followings:\the\parskip
                \begin{subparts}
                    \subpart[1] Height $ME$.\the\parskip\droppoints
                    \subpart[2] Area of base square $ABCD$.\droppoints
                    \subpart[2] Volume of pyramid $ABCD-E$.\droppoints
                \end{subparts} & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,align=t]{example-image-a}
                \captionof{figure}{tabular approach}\label{test1}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{parts}
        %
        \question
        \begin{parts}
            \part
            \parbox[t]{0.65\linewidth}{%
                Figure \ref{test3} shows a pyramid $ABCD-E$. Suppose that $AE=13$, $AC=10$. Find the followings:
                %\par parskip=\the\parskip\par itemsep=\the\itemsep
                \begin{subparts}%\rlap{parskip=\the\parskip{ }itemsep=\the\itemsep}
                    \subpart[1] Height $ME$.\droppoints
                    \subpart[2] Area of base square $ABCD$.\droppoints
                    \subpart[2] Volume of pyramid $ABCD-E$.\droppoints
                \end{subparts}
            }\hfill
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.34\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,align=t]{example-image-b}
                \captionof{figure}{minipage approach}\label{test3}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{parts}
        %
        \question
        
        \begin{parts}
            \part
            \setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-0.34\linewidth}
            \begin{paracol}{2} 
                Figure \ref{test2} shows a pyramid $ABCD-E$. Suppose that $AE=13$, $AC=10$. Find the followings:\the\parskip
                \begin{subparts}
                    \subpart[1] Height $ME$.\droppoints
                    \subpart[2] Area of base square $ABCD$.\droppoints
                    \subpart[2] Volume of pyramid $ABCD-E$.\droppoints
                \end{subparts}
                \switchcolumn
                \begin{figure}[ht]
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
                    \caption{paracol approach}\label{test2}
                \end{figure}
            \end{paracol}
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the `image-c` doesn't align vertically with the text as found in the first two solutions.

Comment: The figure [h] ienvironment adds \intextsep and aligns the top, not the baseline.  You can adjust it using `\vskip-\intextsep\vskip 0.5\baselineskip` or just `\vskip-0.5\intextsep`.