# exam: paracol \setcolumnwidth doesn't work as expected for a two-column part

Tags: floats, exam, paracol

Why does the image in  the second column not fill a width of `0.34\linewidth` as expected?

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.9cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2.2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,paracol}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        
        \setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{2.5cm}
        \pointsdroppedatright
        \marginpointname{\%}
        
        \question
        \begin{parts}
            \setcolumnwidth{0.65\linewidth,0.34\linewidth}
            \part
            \begin{paracol}{2}
                Figure \ref{test3} shows a pyramid $ABCD-E$. Suppose that $AE=13$, $AC=10$. Find the followings:\the\parskip
                \begin{subparts}
                    \subpart[1] Height $ME$.\droppoints
                \end{subparts}
                \switchcolumn
                    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
                    \captionof{figure}{paracol approach}\label{test3}
            \end{paracol}
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `paracol` was started inside parts, the indentation (`\@totalleftmargin`) is applied to both columns. Note also that `\linewidth=\columnwidth-\@totalleftmargin`.

Unlike tabular or minipage, paracol takes up the entire `\textwidth`, not just the remaining `\linewidth`.  The indentation is applied **inside** the columns.  The figure environment ignores the indentation, as it would in a normal column.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.9cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2.2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,paracol}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\definecolumnpreamble{1}{\hskip-\@totalleftmargin}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        
        \setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{2.5cm}
        \pointsdroppedatright
        \marginpointname{\%}
        
        \question
        \begin{parts}
            \setcolumnwidth{0.65\linewidth}% The second column entry is ignored for a two column paracol
            \part
            \begin{paracol}{2}
                Figure \ref{test3} shows a pyramid $ABCD-E$. Suppose that $AE=13$, $AC=10$. Find the followings:\the\parskip
                \begin{subparts}
                    \subpart[1] Height $ME$.\droppoints
                \end{subparts}
                \switchcolumn
                    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
                    \captionof{figure}{paracol approach}\label{test3}
            \end{paracol}
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason I asked this question is that when I remove the float `figure` from the paracol approach in [this question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565686/2288) and use only `\includegraphics`, I don't get the same results of both `tabular` and `minipage` there. Therefore, why does the output of your solution here https://i.ibb.co/gPYGP7d/image.png not look like the expected output as shown in [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565686/2288) in terms of the spacing between the columns?

Comment: Many thanks for the clear explanation. You saved me in three consecutive questions `:)`.  There is one missing setting in your answer `\columnsep=0.01\linewidth` to get the expected output. Thanks and have a nice day/night.