# Including graphics in exam class

Tags: exam, includegraphics

I was trying to include graphics to exam using exam class. All of the solutions to this problem I have found failed...
This is a slice of code which gives me wrong result

```
\question[2]
Czy poniższy graf posiada cykl Eulera? Jaka jest jego liczba chromatyczna?
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{k}
        %\captionof{figure}{}
        \label{label:q3}
    \end{minipage}
%\end{parts}
```

Why ? Look at "tyczna?" word which is in a nonsense position...

[image: nonsense]

Comment: `minipage` is positioned  like a big letter and you have placed it in the same paragraph as the text. Leave a blank line before it and use `\noindent\begin{minipage}` so it isn't indented

Comment: It helps. Thank you very much!

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565686/exam-two-column-questions and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565700/xparse-wrapfigure-intextsep-doesnt-affect-the-output-when-set-inside-a-new