# Center text and images both vertically and horizontally in longtable

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable, includegraphics

I would like to center text and images both vertically and horizontally in a longtable. However I can't seem to get it to work unfortunately. A example is below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array,longtable,ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
 
\begin{document}
       
\begin{longtable}{| l | c | c |}
    \hline
     & Here is a Text & Here is a Text \\\hline
    Here is a Text & \includegraphics[height=2cm]{img/image.png} & \includegraphics[height=2cm]{img/image.png} \\\hline 
    Here is a Text & \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{img/image.png}} & \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{img/image.png}} \\\hline               
\caption{My Caption}
\label{tab:FirstTab}
\end{longtable}
\mbox{}\\    
  
\end{document}
```

I also tried the changes below, but it didn't help:

```
Here is a Text & \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{img/image.png}} & \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{img/image.png}} \\\hline
```

Comment: You should use` \raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\ht\strutbox-0.5\dp\strutbox-0.5\height}`{...}`.  The \strutbox stuff locates the center of text, not the baseline.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19080/134144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `valign` macro from the `adjusbox` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array,longtable,makecell}
\usepackage[demo,               % in real document delete 'demo'
            export]{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx too

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells % add vertical space/above/below cell's content
\begin{longtable}{| l | c | c |}
    \hline
     & Here is a Text & Here is a Text \\\hline
    Here is a Text & \includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=c]{img/image.png} & \includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=c]{img/image.png} \\\hline
    Here is a Text & \includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=c]{img/image.png} & \includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=c]{img/image.png} \\\hline
\caption{My Caption}
\label{tab:FirstTab}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

At using `adjustbox`, we can replace `includegraphics` with `\adjustimage` add determine positions of images in cells with settings in `\adjustboxset`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage[demo,               % in real document delete 'demo'
            export]{adjustbox}  % it load `graphicx` too

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\adjustboxset{height=20mm,valign=c, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt} % <---
\begin{longtable}{| l | c | c |}
    \hline
                & Here is a Text                & Here is a Text                \\
    \hline
Here is a Text  & \adjustimage{}{img/image} & \adjustimage{}{img/image} \\
    \hline
Here is a Text  & \adjustimage{}{img/image} & \adjustimage{}{img/image} \\
    \hline
\caption{My Caption}
\label{tab:FirstTab}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

which gives the same result as the first proposed solution. *Note*, in above MWE are omitted graphics file extensions `png`. They are necessary if there are available the same images' files with different extensions and among them you want to use only selected one.

Comment: And to think of all the time I spent going through the graphicx manual looking for valign!