# Put the name of the matrix tikz besides the figure besides on the left at the middle

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, minipage, text, tikz-matrix

I have done a matrix with Tikz. It is missing just a last point : set on the left in the middle the name of the matrix such I could have : `F_matrix = [figure_tikz]`

I tried :

```
$F_{\text{Big Fisher}}=$
\begin{figure}
  \includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{tkiz_big_fisher}%     without .tex extension
  % or use \input{mytikz}
  \caption{Methodology}
  \label{fig:bigfisher}
\end{figure}
```

but not succeeded.

Could you tell me please how to add this text at this position (middle on the left with the symbol '=' ?

**UPDATE :** I didn't manage to include the Tikz figure in my main Latex source.

I am obliged to generate first a PDF for my Tikz figure and after include it by doing :

```
 \begin{figure}
  $F_{ij}=$\includegraphics{tikz_big_fisher.pdf}
  \caption{Methodology}
  \label{fig:bigfisher}
\end{figure}
```

But the term $F_{ij}$ is at the bottom left of matrix, like this :

[image: $F_{ij}=$ name of matrix]

How to circumvent this issue ? I would like this text to be at the middle on the left like a classical "Matrix_name" = tikz figure.

Comment: Start by placing the F_...= inside of the `figure` environment. Also reduce the width of the included matrix in order to allow both parts to fit into the same line.

Comment: You might be interested in [How to vertically center text with an image in the same row of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19080/82917). This is of course no table but the issue is the same.