# Vertical alignment in table with figures

Tags: tables

Distinguished colleagues, good afternoon.

How can I make the elements of the first column in vertical alignment with the center of the rows?

```
\begin{landscape}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
$R a_{L_{P}}$  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$r=1.00$\\ (Reference Geometry)\end{tabular} & $r=1.05$                                                          & $r=1.10$                                                          & $r=1.20$                                                           & $r=1.50$                                                           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$r=1.50$\\ (Convex Profile)\end{tabular} \\
$3\cdot10^{6}$ & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-1.png}       & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-4.png} & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-7.png} & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-10.png} & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-13.png} & \includegraphics[width=0.1425\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-16.png}  \\
$7\cdot10^{6}$ & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-2.png}       & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-5.png} & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-8.png} & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-11.png} & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-14.png} & \includegraphics[width=0.1425\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-17.png}  \\
$1\cdot10^{7}$ & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-3.png}       & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-6.png} & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-9.png} & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-12.png} & \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-15.png} & \includegraphics[width=0.1425\linewidth]{Figuras/Figuras2/14-18.png} 
\end{tabular}
\caption{2D schematic visualization of the flow lines over the plates with rectangular corrugations with (a) $r=1.00$ (Reference Geometry), (b) $r=1.50$ e (c) $r=1.50$ (Convex Profile)).
Source: Authors' own work.}
\label{fig:Fig14}
\end{figure}

\end{landscape}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at this using the [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)<sup>1</sup> package and the `\raisebox` command<sup>2</sup>.

## Solution

### Code

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                        colspec={X[1,c,mode=dmath]*6{X[3,c,m]}},
                        row{1}={mode=dmath},
                        cell{1}{2,7}={h,mode=text},
                        width=\linewidth
                    }
            R a_{L_{P}}     & {$$r=1.00$$\\ \vspace{-\belowdisplayskip} (Reference Geometry)}                       & r=1.05                                                                                & r=1.10                                                                                & r=1.20                                                                                & r=1.50                                                                                & {$$r=1.50$$\\ \vspace{-\belowdisplayskip} (Convex Profile)}                           \\
            3\cdot10^{6}    & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} \\
            7\cdot10^{6}    & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} \\
            1\cdot10^{7}    & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Figures/TestPicture.png}} \\
        \end{tblr}
        \caption{
                    2D schematic visualization of the flow lines over the plates with rectangular corrugations with (a) $r=1.00$ (Reference Geometry), (b) $r=1.50$ e (c) $r=1.50$ (Convex Profile)).
                    Source: Authors' own work.
                }
        \label{fig:Fig14}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: End result of my code for typesetting this table (with placeholder images).]

## Remarks

I would recommend converting the command into a macro, but I won't do that for now.

---

<sup>1. [`tabularray` Documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/tabularray/0)</sup>
<sup>2. [TeX stac kexchange answer for `\raisebox`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19083)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

- Unfortunately you not provide MWE (Minimal working Example), consequently any information about your document are unknown.
- Since we haven't your pictures (and also don't know their sizes), in MWE below are used draft option to document class, In real document you need to remove it.
- By help of `adjustbox` package are moved images baselines to the vertical centers.
- For shorter code and common settings for images are use `\adjincludegraphics` instead of `\includegraphics` and for them settings defined by `\adjustboxset`.
- Nicer spacing of images in table is used `tblr` of `tabularray` package

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}


\begin{sidewaysfigure}[!ht]
\adjustboxset{height=3cm, % dropout in real document
              width=\linewidth,
              valign = m,
              }
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[c, mode=math] *{5}{X[c]} X[1.1,c]},
             colsep = 3pt,
             }
R a_{L_{P}}  
    & {$r=1.00$\\ (Reference\\ Geometry)} 
    & $r=1.05$                                                          
    & $r=1.10$                                                          
    & $r=1.20$                                                           
    & $r=1.50$                                                           
    & {$r=1.50$\\ (Convex Profile)r} \\
3\cdot10^{6}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-1.png}       
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-4.png}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-7.png}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-10.png}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-13.png}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-16.png}  \\
7\cdot10^{6}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-2.png}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-5.png}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-8.png}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-11.png}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-14.png}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-17.png}  \\
1\cdot10^{7}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-3.png}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-6.png}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-9.png}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-12.png}
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-15.png} 
    & \adjincludegraphics{Figuras/Figuras2/14-18.png}
\end{tblr}
\caption{2D schematic visualization of the flow lines over the plates with rectangular corrugations with (a) $r=1.00$ (Reference Geometry), (b) $r=1.50$ e (c) $r=1.50$ (Convex Profile)).
Source: Authors' own work.}
\label{fig:Fig14}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

If you more prefer `landscape` environment, than instead `rotating` package load `lanndscape` and replace `sidewaystable` with `landscape`. Compilation resulz will be similar as before.